# How can you make a client-side javascript pages with scala.js and sbt's ScalaJSBundler?

Tags: sbt, scala.js, scalajs-bundler

I'm using scala.js to create javascript code to be run in a browser, served up by an akka-http server.  I had it mostly working using mill as my build tool, but then wanted to switch to sbt so I could use the ScalaJSBundler plugin for npm dependencies and packaging.  Using sbt, when I do a fastOpt to compile my scala.js code, javascript code is created slightly different than what mill created and it now includes require statements (which the mill build didn't) such as

```
var $i_react = require("react");
```

When this code is run in my browser require comes up as undefined.  Also variables I have exported in scala.js come up as undefined.  I thought this was because the code being created was for ModuleKind.CommonJSModule (set via the sbt setting scalaJSModuleKind), but when I try to change that to ModuleKind.ESModule the build fails with:

```
scalaJSModuleKind must be set to ModuleKind.CommonJSModule in projects where ScalaJSBundler plugin is enabled
```

I'm new to javascript (and scala.js).  What am I doing wrong?  How should this be done?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [Getting Started of scalajs-bundler](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalajs-bundler/getting-started.html), you should serve the result of `webpack/fastOptJS` to the browser, instead of `fastOptJS`. This is necessary because the latter is emitted as a CommonJS module, unsuitable for the browser, but then processed by Webpack to produce the former, a bundle suited for the browser, also containing the npm dependencies.

Comment: I needed to add the setting: `webpackBundlingMode := BundlingMode.LibraryAndApplication()` and then a `fastOptJS::webpack` did the trick.